# Bluetooth LE getting RSSI Vaule on Raspberry Pi2

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi2, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I'm trying to get the TxPower(RSSI) Value of an iBeacon (BEACONinside, ModelNo. B0001-A) and I'm struggling to get this value into a Python-, C- or Shellscript.
I looked through many Tutorials and Stackoverflow Questions, but (since BLE is quiet new) I'm not able to find anything to start with.

I'm able to get the data on the commandline with

```
sudo hcitool lescan
```

and

```
sudo hcidump -a | egrep 'RSSI|bdaddr XX:XX:XX:XX'
```

But I'm getting also the RSSI value of an BLE-device with status 'random', and no further information for it. My knowledge of regular expressions is pretty limited and so i don't know how i can get only the Data from the device I want.

And as said at the top i would like to get this information into a script so I can use it for further actions.

EDIT:

Here is the output of the hcidump:

```
 bdaddr 20:C3:8F:D1:0E:B1 (Public)
  RSSI: -28
  bdaddr 20:C3:8F:D1:0E:B1 (Public)
  RSSI: -28
  bdaddr 20:C3:8F:D1:0E:B1 (Public)
  RSSI: -31
  bdaddr 20:C3:8F:D1:0E:B1 (Public)
  RSSI: -32
  bdaddr 20:C3:8F:D1:0E:B1 (Public)
  RSSI: -28
  bdaddr 20:C3:8F:D1:0E:B1 (Public)
  RSSI: -28
  bdaddr DD:45:C9:26:61:51 (Random)
  RSSI: -57
  bdaddr DD:45:C9:26:61:51 (Random)
  RSSI: -60
  bdaddr 20:C3:8F:D1:0E:B1 (Public)
  RSSI: -29
```

I know the bdaddr of the devices i want to scan for. so I would like to get only the RSSI for these devices.

Glad for any help

Comment: If I understand correctly it is more of a regex issue and it would be nice if you can show a few lines from the hcidump